# How to find memory leaks of a process?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks

I need to find out the memory usage of a particular process. In fact I need to find out there is any memory leak in the application I have written. I cannot use `memfree` or `/proc/meminfo` since our system has log folder mounted in the RAM.

I have gone through lot of similar queries, and some have suggested to use `ps aux` command. I’m kinda confused on which parameter gives the correct memory usage or maybe memory leak after few hours. `PS AUX` gives `VSZ(virtual mem)` and `RSS(resident set size)`.

I have written a sample program which allocates 4 bytes of memory and De-allocates it. After running the program, it seems `VSZ` value increases when memory is allocated but not decreased when De-allocated. But `RSS` value showed correct, increases when allocated and decreased when De-allocated.

Can anybody confirm whether using `RSS`value will point to the amount of memory leak in the code? Or is there any other method?

Comment: The Operating system can not determine if there are memory leaks in your application. You will never get that kind of information from tools like `ps` or find it in `/proc/meminfo`. The title of this questions asked for "memory usage of a process", but the text asks about memory leaks. One correct answer to that question was given by [Dan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16974256/194894): **Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)** I've edited the title accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

To know the details you can use pmap:
pmap pid

```
root@tm# pmap 1216
1216:   /usr/sbin/acpid
08048000     32K r-x--  /usr/sbin/acpid
08050000      4K rw---  /usr/sbin/acpid
08051000      4K rw---    [ anon ]
088f2000    140K rw---    [ anon ]
b7642000      4K rw---    [ anon ]
b7643000   1280K r-x--  /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so
b7783000      4K -----  /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so
b7784000      8K r----  /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so
b7786000      4K rw---  /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so
b7787000     12K rw---    [ anon ]
b7798000      8K rw---    [ anon ]
b779a000      4K r-x--    [ anon ]
b779b000    108K r-x--  /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
b77b6000      4K r----  /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
b77b7000      4K rw---  /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
bfd59000     84K rw---    [ stack ]
 total     1704K
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is ancient, but I feel the need to say that for something like this, you really just want to use a tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Namely, Valgrind. That's definitely the way to go, especially with a program you're writing (or have written), since you can tweak the compile flags as well so you can get the most useful output. Assuming you're using `gcc`, try compiling with `-g` to turn on debug symbols and don't `strip` the binary.

Usage is pretty simple, and the docs are on the linked website. Basic usage is just `valgrind program` on the command line. It'll show you not only specifics, but a nice summary of memory leaked at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I use top for this sort of thing.

```
top -p <process id>
```